# How to combine 2 drop down value together

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu

I came across an old project created by the previous guy. He has this set of code in MVC .shtml template allow a user to select a time slot. Now I have to combine the 2 selectlist it  into a single selectlist.

```
@{ DateTime from = ViewBag.From, to = ViewBag.To;}

<label>Time slots</label>
@while (from.Date <= to.Date)
{
    var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    <div id="@guid" class="timeslot-subcontainer">
        <div style="display:inline-block;" class="@guid slot-date" iso-date-val="@from.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")">@from.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</div>:&nbsp;
        <div style="display:inline-block;">
            <select class="form-control @guid slot-from">
                <option value="8">08:00</option>
                <option value="9">09:00</option>
                <option value="10">10:00</option>
                <option value="11">11:00</option>
                <option value="12">12:00</option>
                <option value="13">13:00</option>
                <option value="14">14:00</option>
                <option value="15">15:00</option>
                <option value="16">16:00</option>
                <option value="17">17:00</option>
                <option value="18">18:00</option>
                <option value="19">19:00</option>
                <option value="20">20:00</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div style="display:inline-block;">
            <select class="form-control @guid slot-to">
                <option value="8">08:00</option>
                <option value="9">09:00</option>
                <option value="10">10:00</option>
                <option value="11">11:00</option>
                <option value="12">12:00</option>
                <option value="13">13:00</option>
                <option value="14">14:00</option>
                <option value="15">15:00</option>
                <option value="16">16:00</option>
                <option value="17">17:00</option>
                <option value="18">18:00</option>
                <option value="19">19:00</option>
                <option value="20">20:00</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        @{from = from.AddDays(1);}
    </div>
}
```

I want to combine them into a range of time for example `<option value="">8:00-10:00</option>` so that i can get both value slot-from and slot-to

Comment: what is issue in this. It looks like hardcoded values.

Comment: @DeepakKumar Yes but the database has 2 column startdate and enddate now i have to combine this 2 select into 1 and at the same time i can get value from & to from the selectlist <option value="" >8:00 - 10:00</option> the value should be getting from = 8:00 and to = 10:00